# Why is "popular near me" feature in my app store blank?

Tags: ios-appstore, error, iphone

I recently brought new iPhone. I'm not sure why the popular near me feature in app store is blank out..I have enable the location service for it and from the screen shot attached you can also see location icon on top of status bar.

What could cause this?

[image]

Comment: Do you live in New Jersey? :D

Comment: Hahaha..no not really

Comment: Does anyone know why this is happening..Is there something that needs to done that i may ve missing...do note that this is a new phone...brought few days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem, solved it by resetting Location and Privacy in " Settings > General > Reset". Wait for a while after resetting, then the list will appear.

Remember to allow anything related to the App Store.

Comment: What this will reset?

Comment: Will it reset my phone apps,contacts messages or entire phone to factory settings